# Get individual results from CompletableFuture.allof()

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I have a class which issues concurrent requests to two dependent services using CompletableFutures.

My code looks like this:

```
@Builder
@Slf4j
public class TestClass {

    @NonNull private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    @NonNull private final dependency1Client;
    @NonNull private final dependency2Client;

    public void myMethod() {

        RequestObject1 firstDependencyRequest = RequestObject1.builder()
                .attribute1("someValue")
                .attribute2("secondValue");

        CompletableFuture<ResultStructure1> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dependency1Client.call(firstDependencyRequest), threadPool);
        RequestObject2 secondDependencyRequest = RequestObject2.builder()
                .attribute1("someValue")
                .attribute2("secondValue");

        CompletableFuture<ResultStructure2> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dependency2Client.call(secondDependencyRequest), threadPool);

        try {
            CompletableFuture finalFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2);

        } catch (ExecutionException|InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Exception calling dependency", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I need the results from the two calls to the dependent services. How do I get them without performing a blocking call? I was initially thinking that I'd do future1 .get(), but that's a blocking call and I'll have to wait until I have the results from the first API call.

Is there a way to obtain the results from both the calls?

Comment: Why can't you store the results of the two call in a member variable and access them in the next CompletionStage of `finalFuture`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the JavaDoc of `CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) indicates:

> Otherwise, **the results**, if any, of the given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned CompletableFuture, but **may be obtained by inspecting them individually**.

What this means is indeed that you have to call `join()` or `get()` on them. It will not block if you do that in the chain after your `allOf()`, since it already guarantees that all of them are already completed.

Note that in your particular case, if you only have 2 futures, it is probably simpler to use [`thenCombine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which gives you access to the 2 results more easily.